# What is the precision of the UITouch timestamp in iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, touch, precision

How precise is the timestamp property of the UITouch class in iOS? Milliseconds? Tens of milliseconds?  I'm comparing an iPad's internal measurements with a custom touch detection circuit taped on the screen, and there is quite a bit of variability between the two (standard deviation ~ 15ms).

I've seen it suggested that the timestamp is discretized according to the frame refresh interval, but the distribution I'm getting looks continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to the iPad Air 2, the touch detection polling of the iDevices is 60 Hz. The iPad Air 2 is for the first time able to poll touches at 120 Hz.

So while the numbers of the timestamp seem to be very precise (many digits after the dot), they are not.

This is a WWDC video, it's the best WWDC video I've ever seen and it explains everything in detail:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=233

Just because I'm curious: What kind of custom touch detection circuit do you have?

Comment: I didn't think this was happening because I wasn't seeing any evidence of aliasing in the touch timestamps relative to a screen refresh (~800 ms prior). It seems like the video is addressing device latency rather than the time that gets recorded, though. Specifically, I didn't notice any mention about whether events detected during a scan all get the same time stamp, and what that time stamp would be. Also, I was using a resistive circuit that I built myself. It turned out that I couldn't get it to be very reliable without interfering with the screen touch sensor.

Comment: That sounds fairly cool! Touches that get detected at the same "run" all get the same timestamp. You can try this by printing the time stamp and doing a multitouch for 2+ fingers

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So then, is there jitter for when the timestamp will get assigned from one run to the next? It seems implied in the video that the scan happens as fast as possible (which changes from device to device), and so you might expect significant jitter of the scan time relative to the frame start, depending on the device load at the time. Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: I would expect a maximum jitter of 16 ms (one frame). But I'm not 100% sure here. If you find out something, please tell me.  You can also add me in skype if you want to (framusrock).

Comment: This is from an old project that's already been [published] (http://darkball.media.mit.edu/), so I'm not actively trying to solve the issue anymore, but this will probably help in the future. If you don't mind updating your answer with the info from the comments I'll go ahead and mark this as answered.