# How accurate is the UITouch timestamp in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, touchscreen

This question was asked 5 years ago here [What is the precision of the UITouch timestamp in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355850/what-is-the-precision-of-the-uitouch-timestamp-in-ios) and I'm wondering if anyone has any further information or if things have moved on.

To summarize my very rough understanding, an app gets notified once every screen refresh cycle about any touch events, and the refresh cycle used to be 60Hz, and on some devices may be 120Hz.

This would suggest that there are two possibilities.

1. The timestamp coincides with the screen refresh cycle, meaning that the timestamp approximately has the resolution of 60Hz or 120Hz - ie, if you get a touch at 0 milliseconds, the next timestamp you could possibly get from another touch would be at 16 milliseconds on a 60Hz device or at 8 milliseconds on a 120Hz device.
2. Alternatively, it could be that the screen hardware stores the (more or less) exact time of the tap into a buffer somewhere, and then the refresh cycle picks up all the timestamps that have occurred since the last cycle, but these timestamps could fall anywhere in that period. So you could have a tap at 0 milliseconds, or 5 milliseconds or 9 or whatever.

Obviously I'd prefer option 2 to be the case, because in my app I want to know the precise time that the user touched the screen, rather than a value rounded to the nearest 16 millisecond multiple.

Very grateful for any input - thanks!